# How to plot text below xticks (using x-coords) in matplotlib when x-axis are dates?

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, text

I'm trying to plot arbitrary text below the x tick marks in a matplotlib figure (see example figure below).  I'm using dates as the x-axis and, for instance, I want to display counts of some variable associated with each date.

In the example below I use the relative positions from 0-1 within the figure for the x-coordinate of where the text should be positioned.  However I've just guessed these relative values (using trial and error) and so I would like to know how would one plot text below the x-ticks using the actual positions of the x-data instead of using these 0-1 relative scaling that's the default in figtext?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

x = [datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 1, 0, 0),
    datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 0, 0),
    datetime.datetime(2011, 5, 1, 1, 0)]
y = [4, 9, 2]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(x, y, width = 20)

xticks = ax.get_xticks()
xtick_rel_position = np.linspace(0.13, 0.81, len(xticks)) # <- these are just guessed

counts = np.random.randint(0, 25, len(xticks))

for i, xpos in enumerate(xtick_rel_position):
    plt.figtext(xpos, 0.028, "Below tick\nlabel "+str(i), 
    size = 6, ha = 'center')

    plt.figtext(xpos, 0.005, "Count: "+str(counts[i]), 
    size = 6, ha = 'center')

# For better aesthetics
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

[image: desired output]

I've tried including `transform = ax.transAxes` with the actual x coordinates from `ax.get_xticks()` but this doesn't change anything.

Comment: can you please explain your question more? It is really difficult to understand it.

Comment: do you want to just change the text of the `xticklabels`?

Comment: I want to display arbitrary text below each xtick label.  I would like to be able to show the text "Below tick 1", below the first tick on the x axis.

Answer (score 6):

Use **ax.text** for text positions relative to axis positions rather than fig positions:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import numpy as np 

x = [datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 1, 0, 0),
     datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 0, 0),
     datetime.datetime(2011, 5, 1, 1, 0)]
y = [4, 9, 2]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(x, y, width = 20, align='center')

counts = np.random.randint(0, 25, len(ax.get_xticks()))

for i, xpos in enumerate(ax.get_xticks()):
    ax.text(xpos,-1, "Below tick\nlabel "+str(i), 
            size = 6, ha = 'center')

    ax.text(xpos, -1.25, "Count: "+str(counts[i]), 
            size = 6, ha = 'center')
```

[image: newimage]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`date2num`](http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html?highlight=date2num#matplotlib.dates.date2num) function to do the conversion, and a [`DataFormatter`](http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html?highlight=dateformatter#matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter) to display the dates correctly. Finally `get_xticks` is used to get the locations of the ticks for the text to be accurately displayed underneath:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import matplotlib

x = [datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 1, 0, 0),
    datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 0, 0),
    datetime.datetime(2011, 5, 1, 1, 0)]

y = [4, 9, 2]

hfmt = matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%b %Y')
months = matplotlib.dates.MonthLocator(range(1, 13), bymonthday=1, interval=1)

xs = matplotlib.dates.date2num(x)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(xs, y, width=20)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(months)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(hfmt)
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)

for i, x in enumerate(ax.get_xticks()):
    plt.text(x, -1.3, "Below tick\nlabel {}\nCount x".format(i), size=7, ha='center')

fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.15)     # Add space at bottom
plt.show()
```

This would display:

[image: Matplotlib screenshot]

Comment: @P-robot, I have updated the script now I see what you are trying to achieve.